# Has anyone ever seen this in the water?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm on my phone so I hope the picture uploaded correctly. But it's a bunch of lines in the water  and kind of circles around in the one area- it's not the same as the bubbles where fish are active.

Comment: There is no picture

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out why it won't upload. I'm hoping someone knows what I'm talking about based off my description?

Comment: @Jen I cannot locate the meta post to back up my claim, but I vaguely remember reading that new/unregistered users with a low rep are restricted from uploading images.

Answer (score 4):

Those are spots you can pan for ore with the Copper Pan. Doing so you will receive copper, iron, gold, or iridium ore.